# Kivy window crashes after Not Responding without a Python error

Tags: python, kivy, crash, screen, kivy-language

I am trying to make a game using the Kivy library and have a basic menu with three basic screens which all work separately and the traversal between the three works fine as well, however, when I try to initialize the class to start the game and switch to the GameScreen, it crashes after I press the Start Game.

I tried adding a delay to load the menu first using  `timer.sleep(3)`, but that doesnt work. It only works when I do not initialise the GameController class to start the game.

This is the python script:

```
#importing all of the libraries I will be using
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import random
import time

class GameController:
    def __init__(self, num_players):
        self.game_deck=Deck()
        self.players=[]
        self.num_players=num_players
        self.shuffled_deck=self.shuffle_deck(self.game_deck)

    def shuffle_deck(self,deck):
        shuffled_deck=[]
        while len(deck.cards)!=0:
            temp=0
            for i in range(len(deck.cards)-1):
                r=random.randint(0,len(deck.cards)-1)
                temp=deck.cards.pop(r)
                shuffled_deck.append(temp)
        return shuffled_deck
                
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]
        for suit in ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs']:
            for face in range(1,14):
                image=str(str(suit)+str(face)+'.png')
                card=Card(suit, face, image)
                self.cards.append(card)
                
    def get_deck(self):
        return self.cards
        
class Card:
    def __init__(self,face,suit,image):
        self.face=face
        self.suit=suit
        self.image=image

class Players:
    def __init__(self,Username,number):
        self.deck=GameController.deal
        self.name=Username
        self.is_in=True
        self.number=number

##################################################################################

class MainMenu(Screen):
    def close_game(self):
        App.get_running_app().stop() #When this procedure is called, it closes the app
        Window.close()
    

class SingleMenu(Screen):
    def start_game(self):
        game_screen =GameScreen(name='game_screen') 
        self.manager.current ='game_screen'
        time.sleep(3)
        num_players =3
        game_controller =GameController(num_players)  

        

class GameScreen(Screen):
    player_cards=NumericProperty(None)
    current_player=StringProperty(None)

class IrishSnapsApp(App):
    def build(self): #This builds the actual application

        sm=ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainMenu(name='main_menu')) #adds the widget under the name main_Menu
        sm.add_widget(SingleMenu(name='single_menu'))#adds the widget under the name single_menu
        sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='game_screen'))
        sm.current='main_menu' #starts with the application up with the 'main_menu'
        return sm




root=IrishSnapsApp()#creates the root widget for the app
root.run()#runs the app
```

and this is the Kv file:

```
<MainMenu>:
    BoxLayout:
        
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:0.098,0.301,0.2,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding: 50
    
        Label:
            text: 'Irish Snaps'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            id: Singleplayer
            text: 'Singleplayer'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
            on_press: root.manager.current= 'single_menu'
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
        Button:
            id: Multiplayer
            text: 'Multiplayer'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
        Button:
            id: Statistics
            text: 'Statistics'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
        Button:
            id: Closegame
            text: 'Close game'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
            on_press: root.close_game()

<SingleMenu>:
    BoxLayout:
        
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:0.098,0.301,0.2,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    
        orientation:'vertical'
        padding: 50
    
        Label:
            text: 'SinglePlayer'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            font_size: 30
        Button:
            id: Start_game
            text: 'Start game'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
            on_press: root.start_game()
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
        Button:
            id: Number_Of_Bots
            text: 'Number Of Bots'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
        Button:
            id: Difficulty
            text: 'Difficulty'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
        Button:
            id: Back
            text: 'Back'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
            font_size: 24
            background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
            on_press: root.manager.current= 'main_menu'

<GameScreen>:
    
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:0.098,0.301,0.2,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            id: Slap
            text: 'SLAP!'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            pos_hint: {'x':0.7,'y':0.05}
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 0
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Image:
            id: Back_of_card
            source: 'Back_Of_Card.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            pos_hint: {'x':0.425,'y': 0.05}
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.325
        Label:
            text: 'number of cards: {}'.format(root.player_cards)
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1,'y':0.05}
            halign: 'left'
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:1,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: "It is {}'s turn".format(root.current_player)
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.05
            pos_hint: {'x':0.35,'y':0.9}
            color: 0,0,0,1
```

Comment: Try removing `game_screen =GameScreen(name='game_screen')` from your `start_game()` method. And your `shuffle_deck()` method is an infinite loop. Add some prints to that method to see what is happening.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you again for your help, the issue was just that the condition for the while loop was never being met and so it was actually running infinitely.